# Is it acceptable to select your own answer to a question if similar answers exist?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer

This pertains to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99290/can-telekinesis-be-used-to-manipulate-liquids/99299?noredirect=1#comment234535_99299) RPG SE question. I have used a passage from the source book cited by another poster to answer the question in a different way, with a greater degree of concision. However, the original post has more upvotes.

**Is it acceptable to select my own answer over the other, or is it poor form?**

Comment: Ahh... this might be a better question for the [RPG meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/). There isn't really a general answer to your question, anybody that *does* attempt to give you a general answer is going to be doing you (and others) a great disservice. It's *super* case-by-case, and in this case since your answer is *different* than the other answer (so you say in comments, but I am not familiar with the subject material), a meta specific to that community and with more familiarity with the subject would be able to give you better feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting your own answer will not bring it to the top of the answers in the same way as if you selected another user's answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):

> If you accept:
>
> - someone else's answer: You get +2 rep and the author of the accepted answer gets +15 rep.
> - your own answer: There is no reputation awarded and the answer does not float to the top of the list. This can be done no earlier
>     than 48 hours after the question is asked.
> - a community-wiki answer: no reputation is awarded.

If you accept your own answer, all that will happen is it will have a green checkmark by it, so consider whether that is adding anything useful to the Q&A. In most cases, I'd say probably not.

Comment: Would it be fine to just leave the question unanswered until there is an acceptable answer then, even if this would mean question is open indefinitely?

Comment: @MasterArcanist Not accepting an answer doesn't mean the question is unanswered. Accepting an answer leaves the question open to new answers as well, it does not close the question. All it does is signals that the question-asker has found the best solution (in their opinion) to their question or problem. Most of my self-answered questions have no accepted answer, because I want to encourage others to add other – possibly better – answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few elements here

1. Who posted first, and whether your answer was based off that

I mean, if I answered first, and there's a similar answer, I will prefer mine. Likewise, if someone else answered first, I'd rather comment to build on it than self answer

2. What's the most useful.

On occasion my answer included and built on multiple answers *and* other sources, significantly. Its not cool to just say the same thing and self select.

In this case while your source is the same, the *interpretation* is different so they're different answer. At the end of the day, its a judgement call

That said, I like markovchain's answer the best (which might solve the whole problem). It feels like AngryCarrotTop's answer is more based on 'mechanics' and in this case may work better than yours when discussing with a GM OOC.

Alternately *sometimes* its probably ok to leave a question without a selected answer - though in moderation. If you do it a lot, people get annoyed.